# How to solve a fs.file-max value too low?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor

I had an error saying "Too many open files in system", and I read that I needed to increase the value of the fs.file-max variable in /etc/sysctl.conf.

After I ran `ulimit -Hn` which returned 1024, I assumed I would increase this value and set fs.file-max to 4096, and applied this change with `sysctl -p`.

Now I cannot do anything as I get the error "Too many open files in system" for every single command I run.

I read a bit more and it seems I need to set fs.file-max to a much larger value, such as 200000 as suggested in several places.

Now my problem is: how can I edit that value again now? If possible without restarting the machine..

Comment: Actually I can't even run a `shutdown -r now`, so it seems I'll have to hard reboot it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to hard reboot the machine. After restart, I have been able to run commands and remove the fs.file-max value.

I curious however, as to what would have been the solution if I set `fs.file-max = 1` ?